# How to get the index of element in std::map?

Tags: c++, stl

I used `std::map` to save some data, the reason i used map is:

i need to keep the key in order, I need to delete and insert element frequently.

here is a demo:

```
std::map<int, int> a;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) a[i] = i;
a.erase(1);
auto it = a.find(2);  // how to get the index of it?
```

currently, i need to get the index of element, in above example.

I want to know the element whose key = 2, what is its index (the expected is 1, because after those operation, 9 elements left, and key =2 is the second element).

How can i get the index efficiently?

Comment: There is no efficient way to do that with `std::map`. It's not a data structure that has an index notion. `std::distance(a.begin(), it);` will give you "index" in linear time.

Comment: Perhaps what you need is a vector of pairs? What is the actual and underlying problem that is solved by the map? What is the actual and underlying problem that you think would be solved with an "index"? In other words, why do you need the index? What is its use-case?

Comment: @ruakh indices change automatically when elements are inserted or removed, keys do not, keys are `const`

Comment: What are you going to use the index for? Why not just keep the iterator instead? It will not be affected by inserting or removing elements (as long as the element the iterator is pointing at isn't removed of course).

Comment: Looks like [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Why do yo need this? Maybe there is better way to design your algorithm and data layout, so getting needed information in more convenient or fast.

Comment: You're looking for an [order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) (sometimes "rank tree"). Those are not in the standard library.

Comment: What do you want to do? indices are not used in maps. Have a look at std::find, std::remove and/or std::remove_if

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai: Oh, yes, right; I somehow misunderstood what Some programmer dude was suggesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elements in a map don't have an index. They have a key and a mapped value which are `first` and `second` of the iterator, respectively.

If you need a container where elements are stored at certain index you can use a vector:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) a.push_back({i,i});
    a.erase(a.begin()+1);
    auto it = std::find_if(a.begin(),a.end(),[](const auto& x){return x.first== 2;});      
    std::cout << "index = " << std::distance(a.begin(),it);
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/o3663nr4E):

```
index = 1
```

If you keep the vector sorted you could use `std::binary_search` for `O(logN)` finding the element rather the `O(N)` via `std::find_if`.